# Mobil browser displaying large grid instead of small for zurb foundation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I am building a site with zurb-foundation. On a laptop browser everything works as expected. When the window is max size it displays the large grid and when I shrink the size down it switches to the small grid.

When I load it up on a phone however it displays on a large grid. I tried increasing the size of the small grid and phones finally display the small grid at 1000px however this stretches out the content and the fixed nav at the top doesn't get forced into the drop down mode that I want. I am using zurb-foundation (4.3.1). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the view port meta tag which apparently is important lol.

Something like

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' name='viewport'>
```